# Bottom ActionBar Progress Bar Over Button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make a feature where there's a button on the bottom action bar, and once I click on it, a progress bar appears on top of the button and makes the button slightly transparent (not disappear).

I used a custom layout for the top action bar, so on the bottom action bar, I wrote it through menu.xml since I've hard I couldn't have a second custom layout. I was wondering if this feature was possible just from the menu item properties.

Is it possible to make some form of like a frame-layout just from the menu.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a split action bar (uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"), so that the custom layout you use is on the top with the application icon?  The bottom bar is the menu items contained in an XML?

If this is the case, you can specify a custom layout for a menu item by using the layout attribute on the item.  You could make a layout which has both items on top of each other (initially the button is VISIBLE with no alpha and the progress is GONE), then set up a click handler on the item in the onPrepareOptionMenu to set the alpha on the button to make it semi-transparent and change the visibility of the progress bar to VISIBLE.

I believe in the case where you use a custom layout, you can't use the id of the menu item for click handling (onMenuItemClicked), so you'd have to register a click listener either programatically or through the XML onClick attribute.

I apologize if any of the API calls are not 100% correct.  I'm doing this mostly from memory.